# Generate ngrams with Julia

Tags: nlp, zip, julia, n-gram

To generate word bigrams in Julia, I could simply zip through the original list and a list that drops the first element, e.g.:

```
julia> s = split("the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog")
8-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "the"  
 "lazy" 
 "fox"  
 "jumps"
 "over" 
 "the"  
 "brown"
 "dog"  

julia> collect(zip(s, drop(s,1)))
7-element Array{Tuple{SubString{String},SubString{String}},1}:
 ("the","lazy")  
 ("lazy","fox")  
 ("fox","jumps") 
 ("jumps","over")
 ("over","the")  
 ("the","brown") 
 ("brown","dog")
```

To generate a trigram I could use the same `collect(zip(...))` idiom to get:

```
julia> collect(zip(s, drop(s,1), drop(s,2)))
6-element Array{Tuple{SubString{String},SubString{String},SubString{String}},1}:
 ("the","lazy","fox")  
 ("lazy","fox","jumps")
 ("fox","jumps","over")
 ("jumps","over","the")
 ("over","the","brown")
 ("the","brown","dog")
```

But I have to manually add in the 3rd list to zip through, **is there an idiomatic way such that I can do any order of *n*-gram?**

e.g. I'll like to avoid doing this to extract 5-gram:

```
julia> collect(zip(s, drop(s,1), drop(s,2), drop(s,3), drop(s,4)))
4-element Array{Tuple{SubString{String},SubString{String},SubString{String},SubString{String},SubString{String}},1}:
 ("the","lazy","fox","jumps","over") 
 ("lazy","fox","jumps","over","the") 
 ("fox","jumps","over","the","brown")
 ("jumps","over","the","brown","dog")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a clean one-liner for n-grams of any length.

```
ngram(s, n) = collect(zip((drop(s, k) for k = 0:n-1)...))
```

It uses a generator comprehension to iterate over the number of elements, `k`, to `drop`. Then, using the splat (`...`) operator, it unpacks the `Drop`s into `zip`, and finally `collect`s the `Zip` into an `Array`.

```
julia> ngram(s, 2)
7-element Array{Tuple{SubString{String},SubString{String}},1}:
 ("the","lazy")  
 ("lazy","fox")  
 ("fox","jumps") 
 ("jumps","over")
 ("over","the")  
 ("the","brown") 
 ("brown","dog") 

julia> ngram(s, 5)
4-element Array{Tuple{SubString{String},SubString{String},SubString{String},SubString{String},SubString{String}},1}:
 ("the","lazy","fox","jumps","over") 
 ("lazy","fox","jumps","over","the") 
 ("fox","jumps","over","the","brown")
 ("jumps","over","the","brown","dog")
```

As you can see, this is very similar to your solution - only a simple comprehension was added to iterate over the number of elements to `drop`, so that the length could be dynamic.

Comment: Oh cool! Thanks @HarrisonGrodin, didn't know that `drop(s,0)` is possible =)

Comment: @alvas No problem! Also, in the case that `drop(s,0)` was not possible, the following would work. :) `zip(s, (drop(s,k) for k=1:n-1)...)`

Answer (score 6):

By changing the output slightly and using `SubArray`s instead of `Tuple`s, little is lost, but it is possible to avoid allocations and memory copying. If the underlying word list is static, this is OK and faster (in my benchmarks too). The code:

```
ngram(s,n) = [view(s,i:i+n-1) for i=1:length(s)-n+1]
```

and the output:

```
julia> ngram(s,5)
 SubString{String}["the","lazy","fox","jumps","over"] 
 SubString{String}["lazy","fox","jumps","over","the"] 
 SubString{String}["fox","jumps","over","the","brown"]
 SubString{String}["jumps","over","the","brown","dog"]

julia> ngram(s,5)[1][3]
"fox"
```

For larger word lists the memory requirements are substantially smaller also.

Also note using a *generator* allows processing the ngrams one-by-one faster and with less memory and might be enough for the desired processing code (counting something or passing through some hash). For example, using @Gnimuc's solution without the `collect` i.e. just `partition(s, n, 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use `Iterators.jl`'s `partition()`:

```
ngram(s,n) = collect(partition(s, n, 1))
```

Comment: Julia 1.8 now implements `eachsplit`, so you will be able to define `ngram(s::S, n) where {S <: AbstractString} = partition(eachsplit(s), n)`, which will return an iterator.